# Python 2.6 code not running with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I have written a small Python script modeling script.  When I run the code with Python 2.6 interpreter it works perfectly, however when I run the code with Python 2.7 interpreter it throws three Runtime warnings AND has a different output entirely!!

I'm seriously pulling my hair out.  Any help at all appreciated.  I am new to Python but cannot for the life of me understand why the same code works with an older version of Python but not the newer.

### Here is the runtime errors and output when run with Python 2.7:

```
/beta_test.py:57: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  + (np.dot(items, np.diag(items_coef))))

/beta_test.py:60: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
calc_rate = np.divide(util, sum_util)

/beta_test.py:61: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
lklihd = -sum(sum(np.multiply(np.log(calc_rate), volume)))

RSME for model  nan with a log likelihood of nan
```

### Here is the output when run with Python 2.6:

RSME for model 0.00 with a log likelihood of 134259.237914

### And finally, the code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.optimize as op
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------    # Reading in data
volume = np.genfromtxt('data_volume.csv', delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
price = np.genfromtxt('data_price.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
ad = np.genfromtxt('data_ad.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
addisplay = np.genfromtxt('data_addisplay.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
display = np.genfromtxt('data_display.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
adfront = np.genfromtxt('data_adfront.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
admid = np.genfromtxt('data_admid.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
adback = np.genfromtxt('data_adback.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
dist = np.genfromtxt('data_dist.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
items = np.genfromtxt('data_items.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

(n, m) = np.shape(volume)

sum_vol = np.dot(np.dot(volume, np.ones((m, 1))), np.ones((1, m)))
emp_rate = np.divide(volume, sum_vol)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Likelihood Function definition


def likelihood_function(coefs, flag=False):

    coefs = coefs.reshape(-1, (np.size(coefs)/10))

    intercept = np.reshape(coefs[0], (1, np.size(coefs[0])))
    price_coef = coefs[1]
    ad_coef = coefs[2]
    addisplay_coef = coefs[3]
    display_coef = coefs[4]
    adfront_coef = coefs[5]
    admid_coef = coefs[6]
    adback_coef = coefs[7]
    dist_coef = coefs[8]
    items_coef = coefs[9]

    (a, b) = np.shape(price)
    temp = np.ones((1, a))

    util = (np.exp((np.dot(temp.T, intercept))
                + (np.dot(price, np.diag(price_coef))))
                + (np.dot(ad, np.diag(ad_coef)))
                + (np.dot(addisplay, np.diag(addisplay_coef)))
                + (np.dot(display, np.diag(display_coef)))
                + (np.dot(adfront, np.diag(adfront_coef)))
                + (np.dot(admid, np.diag(admid_coef)))
                + (np.dot(adback, np.diag(adback_coef)))
                + (np.dot(dist, np.diag(dist_coef)))
                + (np.dot(items, np.diag(items_coef))))

    sum_util = np.dot((np.dot(util, np.ones((b, 1)))), np.ones((1, b)))
    calc_rate = np.divide(util, sum_util)
    print(sum_util)
    lklihd = -sum(sum(np.multiply(np.log(calc_rate), volume)))
    if flag:
        return lklihd, calc_rate
    else:
        return lklihd
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Preparing for the model


# Define the needed coefficients based on the input data of the same size
initial_theta = np.ones((10, m))
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Likelihood Estimation of the model

# Call Likelihood Function
result = op.minimize(fun=likelihood_function, x0=initial_theta, options={'maxiter':4000})

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Error Calculations Model
(likelihood, rate) = likelihood_function(result.x, flag=True)
error = (emp_rate - rate)
RMSE = math.sqrt((sum(sum(np.multiply(error, error))))/m)*100

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


summary = "RSME for model %4.2f with a log likelihood of %f" % (RMSE, likelihood)
print summary
```

Comment: most of your code is `numpy`/`scipy`, so that would likely be the problem. What versions are you using on each of the interpreters? You are getting over-flow warnings, and you aren't using explicit types for your `numpy` arrays, are your interpreters running as the same type of process? E.g. both 64bit?

Comment: Off the top of my head - are you running a 64-bit version of Python 2.6, but a 32-bit version of Python 2.7?  One way to ensure semi-consistent behavior is to specify your [`dtypes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#data-types) explicitly.

Comment: Are you forced to use Python 2.6? Otherwise it'd be a smart move to move on to Python 3 (or at least stick with 2.7).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am using a 64-bit version of both Python 2.6 and 2.7.  I had thought this might be the issue earlier as well.  I will try using explicit types and see if that fixes my issue, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @Coal_ I want to get this code working in Python 2.7.  When I wrote it I was using a 2.6 interpreter by mistake, but figured it would be no issue to start running the same code with a 2.7 interpreter.  Alas, not so.